# Connect PHP to mysql server running on Mac

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to my MySQL server on a mac using PHP after starting the server using `brew services start mysql` After this I can see that the MySQL server has successfully started. However, when I try to access my webpage using:

```
<?php


/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'databasename');
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

The webpage start spinning continuously and doesn't load. I was wondering what's the issue as I can log into the root from the command line as well as see the tables. And the `bre` shows MySQL server running in the background.

**EDIT** I managed to print my error however, now I get an error:

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory` However, homebrew shows my MySQL server running.

Comment: what errror do you get exactly and have you checked if the service is running

Comment: Yes I see the service running when I see the list of services on homebrew, however, I do not see any errors the windows loader is constantly spinning and my page doesn't come up.

Comment: that is your hole side, if yiou don't get an error the php code connected, try to run `select version()` and echo the output

Comment: @nbk I got the output printed however, i see an error that it cannot while I have connected.

Comment: then enable in in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

```php
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'databasename');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You better make sure if mysqli extension is available in php.ini
   (If it is not enabled, go into the php.ini file and remove ; from the mysqli line.)
2. If mysqlit is enabled, try running the code below and restart the server/terminal php task if anything changes

   ```
   cd /var mkdir mysql cd mysql ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
   ```
3. Check your credentials you give into the mysqli_connect
4. If everything is okay, and you cant still connect try installing helpful programs like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/). They will create an Apache Server with Php and MySql server on local computer without a problem with full configuration